# adding hbm.xml to existing project

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, hibernate, eclipse-plugin

I have project that contains hibernate.cfg.xml file and 3 hbm.xml files of 3 different tabels 
located in MySql each hbm.xml file has a matching .java class. I got all of it as is.

Now I need to create another table and I want to generate its hbm.xml and .java files.

I added to eclipse Hibernate Tools (JBoss) but I can't understand how I do that.

I don't want to create another hibernate.cfg.xml, I want to update it to contain the new table as well.

Comment: you edit the hibernate.cfg.xml and add a reference to the new hbm.xml file...

Comment: my problem is to create the hbm.xml file for the new table. I got the 3 files I didn't create them myself and I can't find how I do it

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to another `hibernate.cfg.xml` config file (esp if you are just adding another table). Create a new `.hbm` file, map it to the corresponding model class and add this config to the existing `hibernate.cfg.xml`.

Comment: but how I create .hbm file for a table? I just managed to create it for some .java file I had..

Comment: Here is a tutorial here to help you: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_mapping_files.htm

Comment: Thanks Kata, but from what I read it is possible to generate these two files (.hbm and .java) using Hibernate Tools (JBoss). The tutorial you gave explains about .hbm files in general and I know that stuff. I want to learn how to generate the files using Hibernate Tools (JBoss)

Comment: @user1692261 http://www.dzone.com/tutorials/java/hibernate/hibernate-example/hibernate-tools-1.html

Comment: Well, it says: create an empty .hbm file and put the following code inside it... :\

Comment: Well, I guess that is the way to do it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25174/discussion-between-kata-and-user1692261)